# Resetting password upfront, before getting email

Tags: password-reset

I recently reset my password on a site that had me enter the new password I wanted to use upfront at the same time I said what email I wanted to reset it for. Then all I had to do was click the link in the email it sent me and it was reset.

I think I actually like this better and may implement any future reset password forms I have to code this way, but I'm just wondering if there are any security issues I should consider with this method (that aren't already present with the traditional method)?

Comment: Have you checked this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018180/best-practice-for-resetting-forgotten-user-passwords/16018373) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not as secure as one might want it to be:

Assume an attacker visits a site and pretends to be some user of that site and to have fogotten the password. On the password reset page they can pre-enter the desired future password and a mail to the real owner of the account is sent.
The real owner receives the mail and perhaps clicks the link because

- they didn't have their morning coffee yet
- for anti-malware purposes they have an automatism that
  automatically GETs any links in mail to pre-scan the content
- they think they didn't request a change, but now that the mail is
  in, it might be a good idea to actually change the password on the change form they expect behind the link
- any other reason

Now the attacker's password has been validated and they can access the account accordingly. Of course, the victim *could* initiate another password reset to limit the damage to a few minutes, but the average user would not think of that. Also, the attacker could initiate a second reset as well and how should the victim decide which of the mails arriving shortly is the right one?

Comment: Good points. Interestingly, the site I did that on was actually a government site.